java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load FFI provider jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider
I am using docker and colima setup to run automation tests locally and encountering this error, that does not seem to start docker.
Error message:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not load FFI provider jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.Provider
stack trace blah blah
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: could not get native definition for type POINTER, original error message follows: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to execute or load jffi binary stub from /var/folders/c3/v1858y9j1n51nyxrcf_6jpx1hgc50n/T/. Set TMPDIR or Java property java.io.tmpdir to a read/write path that is not mounted "noexec".

/{$HOME}/IdeaProjects/cloud/qa-tests/jffi5094755798557333792.dylib:
dlopen(/{$HOME}/IdeaProjects/cloud/qa-tests/jffi5094755798557333792.dylib,
0x0001): tried:
'/{$HOME}/IdeaProjects/cloud/qa-tests/jffi5094755798557333792.dylib'
(code signature in 
'/{$HOME}/IdeaProjects/cloud/qa-tests/jffi5094755798557333792.dylib'
not valid for use in process: Trying to load an unsigned library),
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/{$HOME}/IdeaProjects/cloud/qa-tests/jffi5094755798557333792.dylib'
(no such file),
'/{$HOME}/IdeaProjects/cloud/qa-tests/jffi5094755798557333792.dylib'
(code signature in 
'{$HOME}/IdeaProjects/cloud/qa-tests/jffi5094755798557333792.dylib'
not valid for use in process: Trying to load an unsigned library)

I have tried a bunch of things:

Intalled docker and colima
setup colima: sudo ln -sf $HOME/.colima/default/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
Run colima dn docker
setup docker variables in IntelliJ idea to point to the right location and verify connection



